# how to know when the function was last modified in greenplum?

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

In pgAdmin III tool, we don't find any last modified date of a object like in Oracle.

Is there any way to identify when the function was last modified in Greenplum/PostgreSQL?

Comment: Are you seeking a way to implement such a feature (for future changes) - or is this more of an "after-the-fact" and need to find out when a function had been last modified?

Comment: I am just seeking for any SQL or any system table that gives information on when function was last modified date.

Comment: I understand that. There is no system table that does that - unless you want to mine the logs. If you want to set one up - like an audit table - you could do so, but that would obviously only work for changes going forward.